# Power bi sorting not works for texts which includes numbers

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I want to sort the y-axis as 0-2 days, 3-6 days, 7-13 days, 14-20 days, 21+ days. But it appears as in the image.

I tried StoreText = FORMAT(Test[days], "####") it is also not working. Can someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add an extra column to your data set that has the sort order.  Then you go to DATA tab, select your column with the days in text format, then go to "column tools".  Here you have an option "sort by column".  Set it to the sort order column.